# How to use "deep" XML with MSTest XML Datasource

Tags: mstest, datarow, xmldatasource

I'm having some problems with MSTest using an XML Datasource.  Assume that I've got an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>
            <First>Mike</First>
            <Last>Paterson</Last>
        </Name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>
            <First>John</First>
            <Last>Doe</Last>
        </Name>
    </User>
</Users>
```

My problem, however, is I can't get ahold of the Name element:

```
var name = row["Name"];
System.ArgumentException: Column 'Name' does not belong to table User.
```

I suppose this might be more of a DataRow question but any help would really be appreciated.

EDIT:

Even if I copy the DataRow to a new DataTable and write the XML the Name element is not present:

```
[DeploymentItem("XmlDatasourceTest\\Users.xml"), DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\Users.xml", "User", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var row = TestContext.DataRow;

    DataTable table = row.Table.Copy();

    foreach (DataRow r in table.AsEnumerable().ToArray())
    {
        r.Delete();
    }

    table.ImportRow(row);

    table.WriteXml(@"C:\test.xml");
}
```

For the first row, this yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <User>
    <Id>1</Id>
  </User>
</DocumentElement>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced such problem and this is how I was able to solve it:

```
DataRow dataRow = TestContext.DataRow.GetChildRows("User_Name").First();
string s = (string)dataRow["First"]; // s = "Mike"
```

"User_Name" -- is the name of child relation that binds User table and Name table.